# Custom QGIS 3 Plugin and I get "Couldn't load plugin 'add_layer' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method "

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I am trying to create a basic custom QGIS plugin - all it will do is load a dataset from a list into the current project.

I keep getting the above error and can't figure out what's causing it.

I can't find (the probably small error in the code). The zip with the plugin is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oCQKG1f53a34Ug02hHJFuK0FyLwb0rx4/view?usp=sharing)

## The detailed error is below

```
Couldn't load plugin 'add_layer' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

SyntaxError: invalid syntax 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 335, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/George/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\add_layer\__init__.py", line 35, in classFactory
    from .add_layer import add_layer
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/George/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\add_layer\add_layer.py", line 175
    self.loadVectors()
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.4.4-Madeira Madeira, 73c31df831 

Python Path:
C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/George/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/George/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python37.zip
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\DLLs
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/George/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
```

**UPDATE:
Once I fix the issue** with the ( as per the answer below. I get a new error.

```
Couldn't load plugin 'add_layer' due to an error when calling its initGui() method 

AttributeError: 'add_layer' object has no attribute 'dlg' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 344, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName].initGui()
  File "C:/Users/George/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\add_layer\add_layer.py", line 171, in initGui
    self.dlg.tb_inVector.clicked.connect(self.openVector)
AttributeError: 'add_layer' object has no attribute 'dlg'
```

**Code from Python file** (same as in zip in link above)

```
"""
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction

# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
from .resources import *
# Import the code for the dialog
from .add_layer_dialog import add_layerDialog
import os.path
from qgis.core import *

class add_layer:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgsInterface
        """
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'add_layer_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)

            if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
                QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&add_layer')

        # Check if plugin was started the first time in current QGIS session
        # Must be set in initGui() to survive plugin reloads
        self.first_start = None

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def tr(self, message):
        """Get the translation for a string using Qt translation API.

        We implement this ourselves since we do not inherit QObject.

        :param message: String for translation.
        :type message: str, QString

        :returns: Translated version of message.
        :rtype: QString
        """
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
        return QCoreApplication.translate('add_layer', message)


    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):
        """Add a toolbar icon to the toolbar.

        :param icon_path: Path to the icon for this action. Can be a resource
            path (e.g. ':/plugins/foo/bar.png') or a normal file system path.
        :type icon_path: str

        :param text: Text that should be shown in menu items for this action.
        :type text: str

        :param callback: Function to be called when the action is triggered.
        :type callback: function

        :param enabled_flag: A flag indicating if the action should be enabled
            by default. Defaults to True.
        :type enabled_flag: bool

        :param add_to_menu: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the menu. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_menu: bool

        :param add_to_toolbar: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the toolbar. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_toolbar: bool

        :param status_tip: Optional text to show in a popup when mouse pointer
            hovers over the action.
        :type status_tip: str

        :param parent: Parent widget for the new action. Defaults None.
        :type parent: QWidget

        :param whats_this: Optional text to show in the status bar when the
            mouse pointer hovers over the action.

        :returns: The action that was created. Note that the action is also
            added to self.actions list.
        :rtype: QAction
        """

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            # Adds plugin icon to Plugins toolbar
            self.iface.addToolBarIcon(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

        icon_path = ':/plugins/add_layer/icon.png'
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u'add_layer'),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.dlg.tb_inVector.clicked.connect(self.openVector)
        # will be set False in run()
        #self.first_start = True
        #new
        self.loadVectors()

    def loadVectors(self):
        self.dlg.cb_inVector.clear()
        layers= [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
        vector_layers = []
        for layer in layers:
            if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
                vector_layers.append(layer.name())
        self.dlg.cb_inVector.addItems(vector_layers)


    def unload(self):
        """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginMenu(
                self.tr(u'&add_layer'),
                action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)


    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""

        # Create the dialog with elements (after translation) and keep reference
        # Only create GUI ONCE in callback, so that it will only load when the plugin is started
        #if self.first_start == True:
        #    self.first_start = False
        #    self.dlg = add_layerDialog()

        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        self.loadVectors()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.
            pass
```

**OPTIONS TRIED for issue #2**
 I have tried with self.dlg = add_layerDialog() not commented, I have tried uncommenting the if self.first_start== sections and I have also tried to use the run module from another working plugin {

```
 def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""
        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        self.loadVectors()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.
```

}

I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For your first problem** *(syntax error)*:

You got a missing `)` the line before your self.loadVectors() call... It's a syntax error as your error's traceback says..

**For your second problem** *(add_layer object has no attribute dlg)*:

You never create the `dlg` variable which must instantiate your GUI (class `add_layerDialog`), please have a look to the code of another plugin as every plugins works on the same basis..

It seems that you're a beginner in python programming. I suggest you to learn a little about OOP to understand what going on when qgis run your plugin code. Basically, the `initGui` method is called to add button to QGIS main interface. When you click on this button, the `run` method is called, this is the place where you need to instantiate your dialog in a `self.dlg` variable. In the `initGui` method your plugin does not have any dialog associated.

Comment: Whoops - unfortunately with that changed I am now getting a new error. I will add it to the question.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? It's in the initGUI and LoadVectors - same as in other plugins. I will add the .py code to the question @YoLecomte

Comment: You never define what is self.dlg in your plugin. It must be an instance of your add_layerDialog class.

Comment: Btw it is done in the run method of your plugin but commented....

Comment: Thanks for your continued support -I have tried this but I still get the same issue. See question for details.

Comment: You can have a look at the Qconsolidate3 plugin's code (https://github.com/danzig666/qconsolidate3) which I find pretty clear. It seems to be a good example, close to what you are trying to achieve in the logic.